# codeigniter add wrong extra quote in query

Tags: codeigniter

Please Help me to solve this problem..

i'm going to do query in mysql but code igniter read my query in wrong format:

**my query :**

```
$this->db->select('substring(sbj_prog,1,5) as prog , count(sbj_prog) as bil');
$this->db->from('sbj_app');
$this->db->group_by('prog');
$this->db->limit('10');
```

**this is how codeigniter read**

```
 SELECT substring(sbj_prog, `1`, `5)` as prog, count(sbj_prog) as bil FROM (`sbj_app`) GROUP BY `prog` LIMIT 10
```

the problem is why the extra quote is added to the `5)`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can try extra parameter false like this

```
$this->db->select("substring(sbj_prog,1,5) as prog , count(sbj_prog) as bil", FALSE);
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try to add substring after you get the result like

```
$this->db->select('sbj_prog as prog , count(sbj_prog) as bil');
$this->db->from('sbj_app');
$this->db->group_by('prog');
$this->db->limit('10');
```

Then after you gor the result try to use substring as

```
$prog = substring($row['prog'],1,5);
```

and you can use

```
$this->db->select('substring(sbj_prog,1,5) as prog,count(sbj_prog) as bil',FALSE);
```

Refer this [**Select**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the manual of [CodeIgniter's activerecord](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html);

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. *If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.* This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

In other words, if your case where you only have constants, you can use;

```
$this->db->select('substring(sbj_prog,1,5) as prog , count(sbj_prog) as bil',
                  FALSE);
```